# Finding regex patterns in strings in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I’m trying to create a regex that matches strings that have `/x+any number/` in them, where anything can be written before or after that.

I tried creating the following regex `.*/x+\\d*/.*`

An example of a string I’m trying to match is `abc/x+10/tomorrow`

Strings such as `abc/x+/tomorrow` should evaluate to false but is true.

Comment: is that `+` literal? Or are you saying you want any number of `x`s as long as there is one. Also, are you sure that an input whit out any number is valid?

Comment: Hi! Nice question :-) You could improve it, if you provide some sample strings and a little source code.

Comment: Your regex seems to work fine, did you escaped all the literals properly ? [`Regex Demo  .*\/x\+\d*\/.*`](https://regex101.com/r/50Z27a/1/)

Comment: It works now with the escape characters but found a different error, that I mention in the edited post

Comment: @Carl you need to change `\d*` to `\d+` to make sure atleast one digit should be there

Answer (score 3):

You were very close, all you needed to do was escape all the `/` and `+`, and change `\d*` (match between 0 and unlimited) to `\d+` (match between 1 and unlimited) in order to avoid matching `abc/x+/tomorrow`:

```
.*\/x\+\d+\/.*
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQrb5n/5)

Answer (score 1):

You could use for example [findFirstIn](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) which will return an Option.

You should match 1+ digits instead and the patten can be shortened to `/x\+\d+/`

```
val pattern = """/x\+\d+/""".r
pattern.findFirstIn("abc/x+10/tomorrow").isDefined
pattern.findFirstIn("abc/x+/tomorrow").isDefined
```

Output

```
res0: Boolean = true
res1: Boolean = false
```

[Scala demo](https://ideone.com/Z3CXF0)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
^.*?x\+\d+.*$
```

might simply work with proper language-based escapings.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aiz42U/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/IunvHG/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/IunvHG/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: It should evaluate to false.

Comment: `abc/x+10tomorrow should evaluate to false but is not` but your regex is matching this